# Is the philosophy of neuroscience necessarily materialistic?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, neurophilosophy

The field of neuroscience is quite popular today, as our technology developments allows us for much more depth of research of the brain every passing day.

I understand neuroscience as the field that explores that neurons connections and data transmissions that goes in the brain, and that seem to be like it inherently demands a materialistic approach of the mind. Is it true? Are there neuroscientists (or, if that's even a field, philosophers of neuroscience) that don't support the positive materialistic approach that everything about the mind can be understood from the study of the data transmission that goes inside the brain?

Comment: Note: I'm not sure about the tag "neurophilosophy" I just search "neuro" hoping for something related to neuroscience to pop up but that's the only thing that came up.

Comment: ‘One can no more hope to find consciousness by digging into the brain than one can find gravity by digging into the earth’s centre’. 

Robert Peperell ‘Between phenomenology and neuroscience’ A report of the ‘Towards a Science of Consciousness’ Conference, Prague, July 2003) From JCS Vol 10 No 11 2003 p 87
 .

Comment: @PeterJ thanks! I'll definitely read that. Seems promising.

Comment: Kant correctly observed: "We find not the slightest analogy between thinking and matter." And also: "We know nothing more than that the soul is an immaterial substance, and that it cannot be cognized as the predicate of another being, because I cannot think a composite out of many substances, rather the unity of the subject is absolutely presupposed for that, therefore materialism contradicts itself in the idea."

Comment: @PédeLeão not to undermine Kant, and not to say that he's outdated, but Kant didn't know about the possibilities neuroscience gives us about the study of the brain. While what the quotes you give are on the meta aspect of the question, I still think one shouldn't dismiss a new field of study merely because his view says otherwise.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss. I have studied neuroscience, and Kant's point is just as valid today as it ever was. However, when people say things like that about Kant, they demonstrate a misunderstanding of what *a priori* concepts really are, namely, independence from empirical evidence. It's an absolute independence, such that even 1000 years of science cannot in any way make them more dependent.

Comment: Neuroscience is a research program to find neural correlates of mental phenomena. Insofar as neural is material it is necessarily materialistic. Whether the neural can exhaust the mental is an open question, and one can certainly maintain that it can not, see [SEP's Philosophy of Neuroscience](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/neuroscience). Even then what *can* be correlated (or reduced) to the neural is an important and interesting question.

Comment: @PédeLeão I absolutely understand the a priori statement, but I still hold the somewhat pragmatic view on this - even a priori statements may be reconsidered after receiving new a postriori knowledge, mainly because views can be changed, philosophical statements can be changed, even if there are a priori ones, especially given the fact that even a priori statements are being presented given the current knowledge of the person who presents them. Personal knowledge will always affect our ideas, even if we are in the a priori research field.

Comment: @Conifold I like the last line - "even what *can* be correlated to the neural is an important question". I think this is where my mind was going with when I asked the question.

Comment: It seems a common mistake that people think that new science can undermine old philosophical results. The chances of neuroscience solving the Mind-Matter problem are exactly zero. It would be philosophically very naive to imagine otherwise. .

Comment: @PeterJ isn't what you say already assumes a priori knowledge as much as what Pé de Leão says? If so then as I've said, I think the assumption that a priori knowledge can't be changed is as naive as you say to the other side of the argument. It's all based on the assumption that a priori research is more objective then a postriori one, which is, in my opinion, naive.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss. Continued in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/538/the-symposium).

Comment: @YechiamWeiss - It's not based on a priori knowledge.but on logical analysis. If 2=2=4 in 200 BC then it still does today and it still will tomorrow. Mind-only theories and matter-only theories do not work, never have and never will. This is what we learn from the study of philosophy. No a priori knowledge necessary.other than our perception of Mind and Matter.

Comment: @PeterJ I partially disagree with the first assessment - haven't set theory changed how thinking on the infinity concept? I can't be entirely sure that 2+2=4, unless I limit myself to a certain logic system. But who says that's the correct logic system? Of course, many can be said against such reasoning, but I'm yet to be convinced that our knowledge (even as basic as our logic system) is unchangeable. But this talk is for another question, or maybe we can continue it in chat.
Anyway, what, in all of you guys' minds, is the contribution neuroscience has to offer has then?

Comment: @YechiamWeiss - My example is flawed,  as you say,.but I think the point stands. Philosophical theories that give rise to contradictions do so for all eternity. What does neuroscience offer? Knowledge of the mechanical operation of the physical brain. This is what it studies, As such it is a fine discipline. But when it starts speculating about consciousness it starts looking foolish.

Comment: @PeterJ sure, with that I'm not arguing - that also wasn't my discussion with Pé de Leão. My argument is that, while neuroscience on its own won't inherently tell us about consciousness, the idea that it is possible to check how our brain "works" (even mechanically) might (and probably does, or perhaps should) change our view about consciousness. Maybe in favor of materialism, maybe not. But until the point we actually thought we'll be able to see the mechanics of the brain, we inherently couldn't possibly fathom the possibility of it happening, so it was more possible to belittle materialism.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss - All good. I didn't mean to suggest that a study of the brain would be wholly irrelevant to a study of consciousness. However, most people who study consciousness do not study brains. The materialist assumes consciousness is caused by brains but others would say that physical brains are IN consciousness. I'm not sure that neuroscience has made more than a superficial difference to philosophy of mind but maybe I'm overlooking something.    . ,

Comment: Consider this - we can manipulate the brain and its activities with physical chemical substances. We can halt activities of the brain by cutting off supplies to it or otherwise physically manipulating it. As a result, it is difficult to conclude anything except that we can reduce the brain and its thoughts to necessarily physical, material space and confines.

Comment: @PeterJ please look at what Dallas says in the comment above - though I think I know what you'll say, that this is simply the physical-psychological relation, and that doesn't necessarily mean the mind is necessarily materialistic. Although, as Dallas claims, it is maybe more rational to think that way, because we can't really see the psychological non-physical part of the mind.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss - Dallas makes a common argument but as we know it doesn't settle anything. We cannot see anything non-physical so going just on what we see is bound to lead to materialism, but if we say that there is a non-physical part of the mind then this seems to be the claim that materialism is false. Is there a physical part of the mind? I only ever see brains. Neuroscience need not be materialistic but most practitioners have strong shared opinions on metaphysical issues. I call this counting chickens...

Comment: @PeterJ although Occam's Razor strongly support this argument, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss - In my view nothing really exists, including brains and neuroscientists, so Occam's Razor is my very good friend. I'm unable to see how it would support materialism, which look positively profligate with it's myriad of hypothetical entities. Materialism is a metaphysical theory and neuroscience can do nothing about this. It is a gross misunderstanding of science to think that it can test the theory of materialism. Assuming it is true is very poor scientific practice and I would call it a betrayal of scientific ideals and methods. .